# Does Wasabi accept importing a bitcoin core wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wasabi-wallet

I'm new in this my question is:

I have a Bitcoin Core wallet (full node running on a Linux server).  Is there any way to import the backup file wallet.dat or the private keys to Wasabi wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Does Wasabi accept importing a bitcoin core wallet**

There's nothing on their website to suggest this is possible

Even [importing a watch-only public key](https://docs.wasabiwallet.io/FAQ/FAQ-UseWasabi.html#can-i-import-a-watch-only-extended-public-key) is not supported in the GUI and requires manual construction of wallet JSON data in a plain text editor. This suggests that what you want to achieve is not going to be explicitly supported.